# browse for sql 2008 installation media

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have Windows 7 64 bit. I installed vs 2010 on my machine from ISO file. I have not mount content to CD. I used one software that convert ISO image to CD/DVD media.VS 2010 was installed properly. With VS,sql also came. But when I trying to install sql 2008, from configuration tool-> sql server installation center, it is asking for file. When I am trying to browse that ISO file, that file is not visible in that browse dialog box. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The installer needs to be able to see the setup.exe file and related folders in order to be able to work, it can't read the ISO file directly.

Either extract the contents of the ISO file to the filesystem or mount the ISO as a disc image and point the installer to there.

Comment: I have used deamon tool.So it showing content into another cd device.From that I choose the folder in which setup file exist.But setup.exe is also not visible in browse dialog box.

Comment: You should just need to select the root folder of the installation media, it's just looking for a file path, not for you to specifically choose a file.